# changing URL by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have pages of this type :-

```
xyz.com?q=Apple+Ipod+touch
```

I wish to convert it into type

```
xyz.com/Apple+Ipod+touch
```

How can this be done ?

Comment: Was it intended that Ipad was changed to Ipod in the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you have a more specific format of the URLs, you may be able to refine the `RewriteRule` to be less generic (i.e. not match everything) and more specific to your URLs, but this should work.

Comment: Where do I need to put these ? .htaccess of my domain or the sub-domain I am wishing this to work ?

Comment: Just in the `.htaccess` file in the folder of the sub-domain you want it to work on.

Comment: I used this and its not working

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)*$ ./index.php?id=$1

Comment: (\d+) won't match `apple ipod touch`.  `\d` is only digits [0-9]

Comment: maybe try `RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1` for starting out.